# Proving extensional equality of two functions

Tags: functional-programming, coq, theorem-proving

I came up with two equivalent definitions of a function `applyN` which applies a given function `f` to an argument `x` `n` times:

```
Variable A : Type.

Fixpoint applyN1 (n : nat) (f : A -> A) (x : A) :=
  match n with
    | 0 => x
    | S n0 => applyN1 n0 f (f x)
  end.

Fixpoint applyN2 (n : nat) (f : A -> A) (x : A) :=
  match n with
    | 0 => x
    | S n0 => f (applyN2 n0 f x)
  end.
```

I'd like to prove that these functions are extensionally equal in Coq:

```
Theorem applyEq : forall n f x, applyN1 n f x = applyN2 n f x.
Proof.
intros.
induction n.
reflexivity.  (* base case *)
simpl.
rewrite <- IHn.
```

and I get stuck here. I can't really think of a lemma that would be helpful and easier to prove. How do you go about proving equalities of direct-style and accumulator-based recursive functions without an explicit accumulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to prove it using first a lemma

```
Lemma applyN1_lr : forall k f x, f (applyN1 k f x) = applyN1 k f (f x).
```

proven by induction, then using induction again for `applyEq`.

Note that something I encountered while proving my `applyN1_lr` (and which might have blocked you in your proof attempts) is that you need to have a general induction hypothesis of the form `forall x : A, …`. Indeed, you want to apply this hypothesis with `f x` rather than `x`, and so doing the induction on a fixed `x` will lead you nowhere. To do this you can either completely avoid introducing `x`,  or use the tactics `revert x` or `generalize x` to get the more general goal with which induction succeeds.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was missing. It went much easier after `revert`ing `x`

Answer (score 2):

You could prove an auxilliary lemma, for instance

```
Lemma apply1rec n : forall k f x, k <= S n -> f (applyN1 k f x) = applyN1 k f (f x).
```

(The only external lemma I needed to prove that one is `le_S_n : forall n m, S n <= S m -> n <= m` from `Coq.PeanoNat`)

And the proof is then easy to finish

```
Theorem applyEq : forall n f x, applyN1 n f x = applyN2 n f x.
Proof.
  intros n ? ? ; induction n as [|n IHn].
  - reflexivity.  (* base case *)
  - simpl.
    rewrite <- IHn, (apply1rec n n).
    * reflexivity.
    * apply Nat.le_succ_diag_r.
Qed.
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `n` being a parameter of `apply1rec` helps here. `forall k f x, f (applyN1 k f x) = applyN1 k f (f x)` is also true, but I dont see how this lemma is easier to prove.